# Collection view 4 images in a row

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to make a collectionview with 4 images per row?
Something like this: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0CQC.png)

Right now all of them are in one row:

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="galleryListView" ItemsSource="{Binding gallerylist}" WidthRequest="500">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                     <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout WidthRequest="100">

                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" ></Image>
                         
                    </StackLayout>                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: yes,set the `Span` of `GridItemsLayout` to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify how many columns per row

```
<GridItemsLayout Span="4" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid)